# How does one use Green's theorem to do this conversion of integrals?

Tags: complex-analysis, greens-theorem, complex-dynamics

In Gamelin's book on Complex Dynamics, theorem 1.1 states that for $0 < r < 1$, we set $D_r = C - g(\Delta_r)$ where I used a - sign as opposed to backslash as a set difference, and the $g(z) = 1/z + b_0 + b_1z + ...$ and $\Delta_r$ is the open disk of radius $r$ centered at the origin. Then by Green's theorem,

$\text{area}(D_r) =  \displaystyle\int \int_{D_r} dxdy = \frac{1}{2i}\displaystyle\int_{\partial D_r} \bar{z}dz = \frac{-1}{2i}\displaystyle\int_{\partial \Delta_r} \bar{g}dg$

Now, I understand the bounds on integration since Green's theorem relates an integral within the area to the integral on the boundary, but I don't understand how we go from the first to the second or third integral using Green's theorem. If this could be elucidated, that would be a huge help.

Comment: The boundary $\partial D_{r}$ is the image of $\partial \Delta_r$ under the map $g$. So you are just writing the integral in terms of your parameterization. Another way to say the same thing; it's the change of variables formula.

Comment: Green Theorem shows that $\displaystyle\int \int_{D_r} dxdy = \frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int_{\partial D_r} (xdy-ydx)$, but now $\bar zdz=(x-iy)d(x+iy)=i(xdy-ydx)+(xdx+ydy)$ and the latter part is exact as it is $(d(x^2)+d(y^2))/2$ so integrates to zero on a contour, hence the first equality is clear; second is just change of variables as noted by @Daniel  (noting that $g$ parametrizes the unit circle in an opposite way as it is coming from the outside, so the minus sign in front)